# wikipedia parsing with python - saving the nodes in .edges file

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, html-parsing, wikipedia

So I have this python code with which I get 1000 nodes from wikipedia page, in three depths, 10 nodes from every page.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science').read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#first depth = list1

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True)[:10]:
        print(link['href'])

    #second depth = list2
    sub_html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org' + link['href'])
    sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_html, "lxml")
    for sub_link in sub_soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True)[:10]:
        print(sub_link['href'])

        #third depth = list3
        sub_sub_html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org' + link['href'])
        sub_sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_sub_html, "lxml")
        for sub2_link in sub_sub_soup.find_all('a', href=True, title=True)[:10]:
            print(sub2_link['href'])
```

Next I need to save all the nodes in an edges file. I in the form:

"edge_from_list1","edge_from_list2";

"edge_from_list1","edge_from_list2";

.......

"edge_from_list2","edge_from_list3"

"edge_from_list2","edge_from_list3"

......

Can anyone give me a hint how can I do that?

Comment: Before you attack wikipedia's servers with requests, you do know that you can download *all* of the data for offline usage? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But that doesn't answer my question :)